# Does Angular framework implement constant for a promise that returns immediately?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code that is trying to determine whether or not to execute an asynchronous call depending on a conditional statement.  If the condition is not met, the call is not executed.  Regardless of whether a call was executed, I want to perform some final action.

```
var promise;
if (!hasItemInCache)
{
    promise = getItemAsychronously();
}
else
{
    promise = getPromiseThatResolvesImmediately();
}
promise.then(() => { /* do some final action here */ });
```

Is there something in Angular that does the function of getPromiseThatResolvesImmediately()?  Or do I need to implement it myself and make it a constant in my app?

Answer (score 1):

Simply return a fulfilled promise:

```
function getPromiseThatResolvesImmediately() {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(true);
  });
}
```

It *should not* resolve in the same turn of the event loop, but I am not familiar with `$q`'s API.

Comment: I didn't know you can call $q like that.  That solution definitely works.  However, I was looking for something more out of the box and packaged as one object, such as angular.noop.

Comment: Although it wasn't what I was specifically looking for, it appears to be closest to what I had in mind.  My code now looks like this:
promise = new $q(resolve => resolve(null));

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [deferred API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to always return a promise, no matter if it came from calling an asynchronous function ('if' statement below) or from a synchronous one ('else' statement below)

```
function getSomething(foo) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   if (!hasItemInCache) {

       $someService.get(...).then(function(data){
           // Store your data or whatever.... 
           // Then resolve
           deferred.resolve(data);               
       }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           deferred.reject(status); 
       });
   } 

   // item is in cache 
   else
   {
       // Resolve the deferred $q object before returning the promise
       deferred.resolve(foo); // foo can be whatever you need
   }

   deferred.promise.then( /* Do some final action here */);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know you can do that, but doing it that way means that the final action code will have to be duplicated twice.  Once for inside the promise "then" statement and once in the "else" statement.  I want to be able to declare the final action only once and it should be executed regardless whether the promise came from a get or not.

Comment: Got it, I've updated my answer. Not much changes, you can still use the deferred promise and do a "final action" once it is resolved.

Comment: That is what I had before I asked this question here.  The thing I didn't like (and the reason for asking this question) is that my final action was basically deferred.resolve(/* return same object here */); and in your edited answer, I would still have to repeat that call twice.  Although it obviously isn't a big deal when it's just a simple statement like that, I was looking for a solution that would work in a more complicated case too.  I like that you attach another "then" call to the deferred.promise, at least I can move complicated logic there.  But in my simple case, that doesn't help.